# How to initialize trait's vals in subtrait?

Tags: scala, traits

I tried using an abstract `val` in a trait to initialize another value. I got a `NullPointerException`. I boiled the behaviour down to a minimal test case:

```
trait MessagePrinter {
  val message: String
  println(message)
}

class HelloPrinter extends MessagePrinter {
  val message = "Hello World"
}

val obj = new HelloPrinter()
println(obj.message)
```

This little program yields the following result:

```
null
Hello World
```

I was under the impression that a val may never change. Is this expected behaviour or is it a compiler bug? How can I work around this issue and print `Hello World` during initialization?

Comment: Probably workaround: `lazy val message` or `def message`. The deprecated `delayedInit` (http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.DelayedInit) had a similar purpose. This is a JVM compatibility artifact: http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html

Comment: Sadly lazy vals can not be abstract.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By section 5.1 of the [Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), super classes are initialized first.  Even though `vals` cannot normally be reinstantiated, they do start with a default initial value during construction. You can either use `def`, which has different semantics:

```
trait MessagePrinter {
   def message: String
   println(message)
}

class HelloPrinter extends MessagePrinter {
   def message = "Hello World"
}
```

Or you might consider switching things around like so:

```
class HelloPrinter extends { val message = "Hello World" } with MessagePrinter
```

In which case the super classes are evaluated in order, so that the `MessagePrinter` initialization should work as desired.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `def` in both cases.

One of the sources describing this behaviour is "[Scala Puzzlers](http://www.artima.com/shop/scala_puzzlers)" Puzzler 4:

> The following rules control the initialization and overriding behavior
>   of vals:
>
> 1. Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
> 2. Members are initialized in the order they are declared.
> 3. When a val is overridden, it can still only be initialized once.
> 4. Like an abstract val, an overridden val will have a default initial value during the construction of superclasses.